# Improve performance of writing Django queryset to manytomany

Tags: django, many-to-many, django-queryset

I have a Django 1.11 app. There is a model Campaign where I can specify parameters to select Users. When I run Campaign, I create a CampaignRun instance with FK `compaign_id` and M2M `users`. Each time a Campaign is run, different users can be in a resulting queryset so I'd like to keep a record about it. I do it as shown below:

```
    run = CampaignRun.objects.create(campaign=self, ...)
    (...)
    filtered_users = User.objects.filter(email__in=used_emails)
    run.users.add(*filtered_users)   # I also tried run.users.set(filtered_users)
    run.save()
```

However, it turns out that if the campaign is run from django-admin and the resulting number of   users exceeds approximately 150, the process takes more than 30 seconds, which results in Error 502: Bad Gateway.

It seems to me that 150 is ridiculously low number to get a timeout so I believe there must be a plenty of room for optimizing the process. What can I do to improve this process? What are my options in Django? Would you suggest using completely different approach (e.g. nosql)?

Comment: Do you know which exact query take that much time. Mb worth checking with debug-toolbar?

Comment: Consider that ```email__in==``` is also a heavy query because of VARCHAR. Maybe you need to add db_index to it

Comment: If you are querying CampaignRun and its users somewhere, it could take long as you will hit the database 150 times for each iteration of CampaignRun